# extract values from a vector$level[#]...ugh

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have been trying to do something and its getting really sloppy, but its OK because I wont need to do this again.  I just need to look at this once.

So I have these 'by' objects.  The are structered as object$factorlevel[3]

Basically, I have to loop through all factor levels extracting the 3rd position of data from the by object.

I want to end up with

```
factorlevel   datafrom3rdposition
factorlevel   datafrom3rdposition
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a clearer example case, with a sample input data and the sample output.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here:  http://bit.ly/SORepro    -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the part in the OP that says `"The are structered as object$factorlevel[3]"`, I am assuming what you are calling `factorlevels` corresponds to a factor elsewhere, not in `object`.

Try the following.

```
lapply(object, "[[", 3)

# use sapply for a vector, assuming each 3rd element is a single element
sapply(object, "[[", 3)
```

If this does not work, please post an actual sample of your data.

Comment: That got me very close to what I wanted.  Unfortunately, I still don't know how to deal with the result.  $factor
[1] 0.12323  -  How could I, for example, do a mean on the result?  Thanks!

Comment: The result is a list.  If you want a vector, use `sapply` instead.  Please click on the `R` tag, then click on `about`.  This will take you to a page with several documents.  The `R intro` pdf is a great place to start